# How to set root directory in dreamweaver to access /home/<user>/public_html/

Tags: dreamweaver, cpanel

I'm using cpanel for the first time on a new site. In dreamweaver if I leave the "root directory" blank dreamweaver will write to /home/*username*/ with no problems.
However if I try to set the root directory to /home/*username*/public_html/ (or just /public_html) as the documentation insists I cannot connect.
I would switch to standard linux but the hosting company insists I use cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a guy on youtube I have set this up. The link to the video is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pI2lsUY7u9w